# Yii2 rules for validating percentage like 65.45

Tags: php, regex, yii2, preg-match, rules

I know this is very simple and repeated question, But i tried almost all but didnt get any solution.
I want to validate a percentage of student like. Eg: 65.45..
The user has to enter value like this only otherwise it should show error.
I have given below rules in the model. But its taking only integer values. Not validation for percentage.

```
[['c_percentage'], 'number', 'numberPattern' => '/^\s*[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?\s*$/'],
```

Please help to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding *its taking only integer values*: the pattern is [correct](https://regex101.com/r/L6kPWD/1), it allows matching both integer and float values, are you sure you are checking/assigned the rule to/ the right element? Note that `[0-9]*` matches 0 or more digits, and `[.,]?` matches 1 or 0 commas/periods.

Comment: Regarding to your requirement *The user has to enter value like this **only*** modify it to be like this: `/^\s*[-+]?[0-9]+[.,][0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?\s*$/`

Comment: Or if the scientific notation should not be allowed, use a much simpler `/^\s*\d+[.,]\d+\s*$/`

Comment: Thank you for replies.. Its still dos'nt work. its accepting values like 55.6666. i want to take value like 55.66

Comment: What if you also replace `'numberPattern'` with `'pattern'`?

Comment: yeah did tat and i have to change `number` to `match`. Even now its same as previous. Taking values if i enter 55.66666

Comment: isn't it is possible to restrict only two digit after `.` Dot symbol??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
/^\s*[+-]?\d+(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?\s*$/
```

**Explanation:**

```
/               : regex delimiter
  ^             : begining of string
    \s*         : 0 or more spaces
    [+-]?       : optional plus or minus
    \d+         : 1 or more digits
    (?:         : start non capture group
      [.,]      : dot or comma
      \d{1,2}   : 1 or 2 digits (decimal part)
    )?          : the group is optional to allow whole integer
    \s*         : 0 or more spaces
  $             : end of string
/               : regex delimiter
```

If you want to match only float values, remove the optional part:

```
/^\s*[+-]?\d+[.,]\d{1,2}\s*$/
```

or, if you want exactly 2 decimals:

```
/^\s*[+-]?\d+[.,]\d{2}\s*$/
```

Comment: Does it work if you change the non capture into a capture group (ie. remove `?:` at the begining of the group) ?

Comment: Partially working. its now not showing error msg if i enter eg: 55.

Comment: @SalmanRiyaz: Do you want to accept whole integer (ie. `45`) or only float with 2 decimal max?

Comment: i want float with 2 decimals. Like 45.55

Comment: I would just add a ['c_percentage', 'compare', 'compareValue' => 100, 'operator' => '<='] to ensure that its is not more than 100.00%

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will validate

```
[['c_percentage'], 'number', 'numberPattern' => '/^[0-9]{1,2}(\.([0-9]{0,2})){0,1}$/'],
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.. Its still dos'nt work. its accepting values like 55.6666. i want to take value like 55.66

Comment: 55.6666 is valid percentage, do you want accpet only 55.66 right?

Comment: check now answer

Comment: yes i want only 55.66-  the updated answer also did'nt work